# 'windows-1255' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: silverlight, character-encoding, silverlight-5.0

I'm writing a silverlight 5 application in which I need to read a text file from the user.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")))
```

But I get the exception: "'windows-1255' is not a supported encoding name".
Why is that?

And then, how do I read a file in the "windows-1255" encoding? (Hebrew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ran into this problem again,

And after lots and lots of Googleing i found this **amazing** tool!

http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator

this little piece of art that was created by "Philipp Sumi (@phsumi)", takes the name or code page of a well known encoding, and creates a custom Encoding class which compiles under Silverlight.

it does so by reading the existing encoding in wpf, and redactor it to work under silverlight.

Comment: Nice find! A little explanation of what it does in your answer would be great, if the link goes dead.

Comment: @jv42 Good point, i added a description of the tool and also the name of the creator with his twitter account, so you can contact him in the event of the link going dead.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many supported encodings in Silverlight. Basically, you get UTF8 and UTF16, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28VS.95%29.aspx

You can read your file as binary then convert yourself to UTF (8 or 32, I don't know Hebrew). You'll need a table of all the characters (256), then you can loop on your input file and translate directly.

Comment: :O really? =[  but silverlight 5 is suppose to support all languages isn't it?

Comment: Languages and encodings are two very different things.