# Encoding byte[] to iso-8859-2

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How I can encode a byte array to iso8859-2 in Windows Phone 8.1 app?
I have something like this

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     var response = client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);  
}
```

I found the following code but it doesn't work because response.Length does not exist in WP 8.1.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);
    var responseSting = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
}
```

**Edit**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_2 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859_2");
    var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);
    htmlPage = iso_8859_2.GetString(response, 0, response.Length);
}
```

Comment: `response.Length` definitely *does* exist in WP8.1. The `Length` property of an array is a core part of the C# language. Note that you shouldn't have the `- 1` there... why are you trying to ignore the last byte?

Comment: And why are you using `Encoding.UTF8` if you actually want ISO-8859-2?

Comment: You've got `Task<byte[]>` and not `byte[]`

Comment: I think you're missing a `await` keyword. It should be `var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);` and whatver Jon said.

Comment: All the above, and also it's already encoded when you've an array of bytes, you're trying to decode it.

Comment: Siriam Sakthivel thanks for await. Above is my new code but iso-8859-2 is not a supported encoding in WP 8.1. Any other ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20141188/4081152 - this is solution