# Windows -1252 is not supported encoding name

Tags: c#, mysql, encoding, arm, windows-1252

I am working with windows 10 universal App and the ARM CPU to create apps for the Raspberry Pi.  I get the following error with encoding:

> Additional information: 'windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

```
 private async void Login(string passcode)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=...");
            MySqlCommand cmd;

            conn.Open();

            cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from ...");

            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;

            while (dr.Read())
                count += 1;

            var dialog = new MessageDialog((count == 1) ? "Logged In" : "Error");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
           await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
    }
}
```

I get the error in this line of code

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Before I used to get it in

```
conn.open();
```

But I was able to solve it by adding

```
charset=utf8
```

to the connection string.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Not sure what question you still have as " I was able to solve it by..." is last part of the post... Please replace thank you notes with exact question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563973/windows-1255-is-not-a-supported-encoding-name

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well I was able to solve it when I got the same error in the line code "conn.open();" However, Now I am getting this error in the line "dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();" Does that clarify it?

Comment: @vnikhil Thank you, But this doesn't work for my situation

Comment: cp1252 is quite close to MySQL's "latin1" `CHARACTER SET`.

Answer (score 55):

From a .NET Core 2.2 project, I had to install *via Nuget* the following two packages:

[image: System.Text.Encoding | CodePages]

(System.Text.Encoding & System.Text.Encoding.CodePages)

Then you have to set it before the use of libraries:

```
 using System.Text;
 …
 {
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: This fixed it for me and seems like a more proper way of fixing the issue.

Comment: Fixed my issue with DataTable.ReadXml(fileName); ΩmegaMan saved my day.

Answer (score 40):

I resolved this issue by adding

```
System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
```

Comment: This is correct anwser ! It help me fix my problem ! Thanks !

Comment: As @ΩmegaMan noted, for .NET Core/Standard project you need to add NuGet package ```System.Text.Encoding.CodePages``` to references.